# Trying to Create Homepage with Random Background Image Each Time it is Accessed. Using HTML and JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

I'm trying to make an array of multiple background images and having the browser choose one at random to display.

I have attempted coding with some help but don't know where I'm going wrong.

Here is the code I am working with

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Christopher Tameji Foose</title>
<script src="chrisfoose.js">

var imgSrcArr = ["/background/000.jpg", "/background/001.jpg", "/background/003.jpg"]

    window.onload = function() {
            var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        console.log(randNum);   document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgSrcArr[randNum] + "')";
        }

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

    ;<script>

    ;</script>
```

A zip of my website is at https://www.sendspace.com/file/2la4he.  Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You entire CodePen doesn't display due to unverified email address.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: to accept an answer you just hover beside the answer and you will see a tick appear. click it. it means 15 points for the answerer and a badge for you when you first accept an answer. You should try it! 2 questions with no ticks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here. First, `document.getElementByTagName("div.main")` is invalid since there is no function called "getElementByTagName" What you want is "getElement**s**ByTagName" (notice the extra "s").

Second, your target `div` has an ID, so rather than looping through all the tags and selecting the one you want, just use `getElementById()` instead.

```
var imgSrcArr = ["/background/000.jpg", "/background/001.jpg", "/background/003.jpg"]
window.onload = function() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgSrcArr[randNum] + "')";
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fvo6v0vL/

Comment: HAHA! Good answer, Dryden! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript has a syntax error. It's `getElementsByTagName`. You're missing the 's'.

Alternatively, I recommend you use `getElementById`, that way you only select the one `main` object:

```
var imgSrcArr = ["/background/000.jpg", "/background/001.jpg", "/background/003.jpg"]

window.onload = function() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgSrcArr[randNum] + "')"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the snippet below to see the result:

```js
var imgSrcArr = ["http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/running_horse-wide.jpg", "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/colorful_background-wide.jpg", "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/moonlight_cruise-wide.jpg"]

window.onload = function() {
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgSrcArr[randNum] + "')"
}
```

```css
a {text-decoration: none;color: white}
.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}
.center {float: center;}
div.main {
  margin: auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  backgroud-repeat: no-repeat border: 1px solid black;
}
body {background-color: black;}
#main {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#vid {
  width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#circle {position: fixed;z-index: 1;}
#buttonred {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonblue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttongreen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonpink {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonorange {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttonback {
  witdth: 100px;
  height 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
;
table.center {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table.center {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 300px;
  color: white;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial, Terminal, Times New Roman;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
p.bio {
  font-family: Terminal, Arial;
  color: black;
}
td.bio {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Courier, Terminal, Arial;
  padding: 50px;
}
table.bio {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
table.video {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
table.graphics {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px border-color: white;
}
td.graphics {
  border: 1px solid white;
  align: center;
}
#videobanner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
}
p.video {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: large;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main">

  ;
  <table class="center" id="tablecenter">
    <td>
      <div id="buttonred">
        <p><a href="who.html">Who?</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="buttonblue">
        <p><a href="resume.html">Resume / CV</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="buttongreen">
        <p><a href="video.html">Video</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="buttonpink">
        <p><a href="graphics.htm">Graphics</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="buttonorange">
        <p>Projects</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    ;</table>

</div>
```

I used `getElementById` instead and you can access the `style` object directly through it (no need to access the first position the array with `[0]` as [w3schools explain](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)).